# how can i get the right string from a byte array which is passed over by DatagramSocket

Tags: java, sockets, udp

here is the code i send the string:

```
byte[] buffer = txtAreaSendText.getText().getBytes();// Point A
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,remoteAddr, remoteTextPort);
udpSocket.send(dp);
```

and here is my code for receiving the string:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 1024);
try {
    udpSocket.receive(dp);
    String txtString = dp.getData().toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i try to correct the code by change the code at Point A:

```
byte[] buffer = txtAreaSendText.getText().getBytes("utf-8");
```

but i can not get the right string as well.

plus, my default encoding of eclipse workspace is utf-8,and java file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i can not get the right string as well.

What are you getting?

From the looks of it you're calling `toString()` on a byte array and it probably returns the class type as a string (or something similar).

I believe what you should be doing is:

```
byte[] data = dp.getData()
String txtString = new String(data);
```

Comment: Always use a specific, explicit encoding when using String.getBytes() and new String(byte[]), else the default platform encoding is used, and thus one side could use UTF-8 and the other side could use ISO-8859-1, which won't lead to the expected result.